# Pinta Not Closing

Tags: 14.04

I am using Pinta and when I go to close it I get an error:
Unhandled exception:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Here are the details I get:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Pinta.Core.SettingsManager.Serialize (System.String filename, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 settings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.Core.SettingsManager.SaveSettings () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.MainWindow.SaveUserSettings () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.MainWindow.<MainWindow>m__34 (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.Core.FileActions.RaiseBeforeQuit () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Pinta.Actions.ExitProgramAction.Activated (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.Signal.ClosureInvokedCB (System.Object o, GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.SignalClosure.Invoke (GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback (IntPtr raw_closure, IntPtr return_val, UInt32 n_param_vals, IntPtr param_values, IntPtr invocation_hint, IntPtr marshal_data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Any help appreciated. I am using Ubuntu 14.04
I tried to close it in the terminal using `sudo killall pinta` and the terminal says no process found.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, same problem here, and I couldn't fine a proper solution, however opening any image and then closing it works for me.

NB: Can't reproduce at the moment though.